# table view is not showing my custom cell

Tags: ios, tableview

i want to show a customised cell in my table view. i did these steps correctly

- add a table view to the story board.
- design the cell with two buttons , one image view,and three labels.
- add a class for the cell and sub class it by uitableviewcell
- in .h file i set the iboutlets for labels,image views.

in my table view controller class i did these things

- get some values from a web service and load it to array in viewDidload.
- in cellForRowAtIndexPath i have create the cell and just load some values which i need to display in the cell. for testing i just give a sample text to a label .

but when i run the app the designed cell does not display. only empty row is there.

what is the wrong i did... i cant understand...please someone help me..

below is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
 // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
duplicateCell *cell = (duplicateCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.delegate_D = self;
 //  TacleCell *cell = (TacleCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
//cell.delegate = self;
// Configure the cell...

NSArray* currentDuplicates = [self.duplicateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"DUPLICATE IN DUPLICATE:%@",currentDuplicates);

cell.Name_D.text = @"test name";


return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSLog(@"COUNT:%d@",[self.duplicateArray count]);

return [self.duplicateArray count];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
 //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
[self.tableView registerClass:[duplicateCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
self.title = @"Duplicate Req";
self.duplicateArray = [TableViewController getDuplicateList];
NSLog(@"DUPZ %@",self.duplicateArray);

}
```

please someone help me...

EDIT : below images will help you to understand my case i think..

[image: second view is the one i got trouble]

[image: i gave cell Identifier like this]

here is my story Bord.. as you can see the last view controller (in the right corner) is the one im talking about. the one is left next to it do the same functionality, but it works like a charm. i applied the same codes, same steps followed. why this is not show me the correct result..?

[image: story board]

I HAVE SOLVED THE ISSUE..I HAVE GIVEN A WRONG SEGUE. WHAT I DID WAS , I CREATE A SEGUE BETWEEN TWO TABLE VIEWS AND PERFORM THE SEGUE IN MY ALERT VIEW..NOW WORKS FINE...

THANK YOU EVERYONE WHO GUIDE ME..

Comment: remove the registerClass from viewDidLoad and check again **Name_D** connected to the class file

Comment: Has the cellIdentifier been provided to the cell in storyboard?

Comment: yeah i didnt included it.. but when i run the app it gave me error in the line number two in cellforRowAtindexpath method. that is why i included that line. if i remove it , it gives me this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: @Darshana, theres your problem. In your XIB or storyboard you should have the same cell identifier you are using when intializing. So go to your XIB or storyboard and paste the string "cell" in cell identifier section.

Comment: C my edited question... i have done the things you all mentioned... but didn't worked still

Comment: @Darshana, you seem to have done it right. Are you sure `NSLog(@"COUNT:%d@",[self.duplicateArray count]);   return [self.duplicateArray count];` is not returning 0 ?

Comment: @AppleDelegate  yes i have uploaded the images also to my question...

Comment: @iNoob yes it is not return zero...

Comment: @Darshana, Oh okay, then only thing i can guess is you forgot to set delegate and datasource of table view.

Comment: @iNoob  no sir i have add these lines to my .h file in the table view controller        "@interface DuplicateViewViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITabBarDelegate,DuplicateDelegate>"

Answer (score 0):

U need to initialise the cell when its not received by deque.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
 // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
duplicateCell *cell = (duplicateCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell == nil)
{
cell = [[duplicateCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey make an custom UITableViewCell class with xib and draw cells in xib.

then use this code in your tableView class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    duplicateCell *cell = (duplicateCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"duplicateCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```